# Horizontal Line next to text on black background with html

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble displaying a white horizontal line in a div with a black background next to a heading.

This is what I've tried:

```html
<div style="background-color: black">
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px #ededed solid; overflow: visible; height: 17px; margin: 5px 0 10px 0">
        <strong><span style="color: white; padding: 0px 5px; font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Willkommen</span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: add an image with your required layout to make it more clear

Comment: Where in your html is the white horizontal line? Or do you want to add it to the html? Where do you want to put the white horizontal line?

Comment: @SanjayNishad I added it

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the height in second div tag as I believe 17px is too low

Comment: I just added a picture to show you what I mean could you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-decoration` and `text-decoration-color` CSS properties for the same.

```html
<div style="background-color: black; padding: 15px 10px">
    <div style="overflow: visible; height: 17px; margin: 5px 0 10px 0;">
        <strong><span style="text-decoration: overline;text-decoration-color: #ededed ;color: white; padding: 0px 5px; font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Willkommen</span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

another option you can use is `<hr/>` HTML tag

```html
<div style="background-color: black; padding: 10px 10px 25px 10px">
    <div style="overflow: visible; height: 17px; margin: 5px 0 10px 0;">
    <hr/>
        <strong><span style="color: white; padding: 0px 5px; font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Willkommen</span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update as per image-**

You can use Sean's answer

another trick you can try with the below style

```css
.line {
    white-space: pre;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black; padding: 50px 10px">
    <div style="overflow: visible; height: 17px; margin: 5px 0 10px 0">
        <strong><span style="color: white; padding: 0px 5px; font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Proxima Nova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Willkommen
        <span class="line">                  </span>
        </span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: more text-decoration styles you can use-
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-decoration

Comment: `<hr>` elements should only be used semantically to denote thematic breaks between paragraph-level text. They shouldn't be used to create decorative lines.

Comment: Yeah you are right, better to use another element with border style, we can't suggest something better until we get the actual requirement

Comment: I just added a picture to show you what I mean could you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a combination of a pseudo-element and grid. This avoids the need for unnecessary extra markup, and will adapt to any width.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #ededed;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Willkommen</h1>
```

---

If you have to use inline styles, you'll need to add an additional element like a span to take the place of the pseudo-element, like this:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;">
  Willkommen
  <span style="
    display: block;
    background: #ededed;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 0.25em;">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added a picture to show you what I mean could you have a look at it?

Comment: @weborca I've revised my answer based on the image you provided.

Comment: Thanks that looks great! Is it possible to use the css as inline of an div html element?

Comment: @weborca why does it need to be inline? is it for an email?

Comment: Because I'm inserting it somewhere where you can only add html